# Cypress custom command is not recognized when invoked

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

I've created the following custom command in my `cypress/support/commands.js` file.

```
Cypress.Commands.add("login", (username, password) => {
    cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        form: true,
        url: '/test/login/',
        body: {'username': username, 'password': password}
    })
})
```

I had tests passing and login working before moving the login functionality to this custom command. I'm invoking it in my spec with `cy.login(testuser, testpwd)`, but I'm getting the following error message: `TypeError: cy.login is not a function`. The [docs say](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Syntax) that /cypress/support/commands.js is loaded before any test files are evaluated, so I assumed that simply placing a custom command in there would make the command available.  I'm running the tests through the local (GUI) test runner.

Comment: Can you confirm that the `index.js` file within `cypress/support` has this line of code? `import "./commands"`

Comment: Yes, I've now un-commented that line in index.js.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

All the code and referenced modules in `index.js` are loaded before your test file. So you need to refer(require) `commands.js` in your `index.js` file. 
You can however import `commands.js` module directly in your test file but then you need to include it every test file.
Recommended approach is to include it in `index.js` file and you are not worried about explicitly refer in your test files.

Comment: Thank you.  In [this section of the docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Syntax) it says:  "A great place to define or overwrite commands is in your cypress/support/commands.js file, since it is loaded before any test files are evaluated."  From that it sounded like no import of commands.js is required, so it never occurred to me to try that.  Similarly, for index.js they say that it is imported prior to running any spec "so you don’t have to import this file in every single one of your spec files" - but I had to import index.js and, within it, import commands.js.

Comment: I also think it's not particularly clear from the docs... Will expand on this answer with a sample.

Comment: Will this work with different user names and passwords in each spec file? I've used your suggestions, and updated my login to use variables so I can have the user i need in each spec, however it always logs in now as userA, it never uses userB from this other spec.  I'm not sure how Command is even getting a user name and password if it's not taking it from my spec i'm running.

Comment: Dan Swain Now the official (& updated) document says-A great place to define or overwrite commands is in your cypress/support/commands.js file, since it is loaded before any test files are evaluated via an import statement in your supportFile (cypress/support/index.js by default).

Answer (score 12):

To expand on @Dinesh Kumar's excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47707642/3249501), it's also important you haven't disabled support for the default support file (I know, unfortunate naming scheme in this case) inside your `cypress.json` by adding the line: `supportFile: false`.

Delete that line from your `cypress.json` if it's there. You can also specify a different path if you're not happy using the default path of `cypress/support/index.js`.

Working index.js with commands.js file - both in the `support` folder:

```
// index.js
const customCommands = require('./commands.js')

module.exports = {
  commands: customCommands
}
```

And double check your settings:

```
// cypress.json
{
  "baseUrl": "http://demo.your-domain.test",
  "supportFile": false,  // <-- delete this line present
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using typescript and just needed to set `"supportFile": "cypress/support/index.ts"`

Answer (score 3):

It may help to put a line `import './commands.js'` into `index.js`.

Comment: A great place to define or overwrite commands is in your cypress/support/commands.js file, since it is loaded before any test files are evaluated via an import statement in your supportFile (cypress/support/index.js by default).

Comment: It should be `import './commands.js';` without the slash since `commands.js` is a file.

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked when I added the type signature of the custom command in the file cypress/support/index.d.ts. For more information visit: [Cypress example - Custom Commands](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-todomvc#custom-commands)

```
declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable {
    clearLocalStorageIframe(): void
  }
}
```

I am using 7.2.0 Cypress and `command.ts` and `index.ts` file extension I have changed it to .ts

Answer (score 1):

I'm using cypress version 12.16. This is my **cypress.config.js**

```
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
    supportFile: "cypress/support/index.js",  <------ refer the index.js file into support folder
  },
})
```

Then the **index.js** file is importing my customs commands

```
import './commands'
```

My **commands.js** file

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (url, user) => {
    //..
})
Cypress.Commands.add('logout', () => {
    //..
})
```

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr

Wrap the `Cypress.Commands.add`s to a function then import and run it.

### Explanation

I had all my `Cypress.Commands.add`s in the `support/commands.ts` file. This was imported in `support/e2e.ts` with `import './commands';` which worked fine until a recent dependency upgrade. To make it work again I modified the `support/commands.ts` file so it looks like this:

```js
export default function addCustomCommands() {
  // all the Cypress.Commands.add calls
}
```

Then imported and executed this function in the `support/e2e.ts` file:

```js
import addCustomCommands from './commands';

addCustomCommands();
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Check if your IDE tried to resolve `cy`

I slipped into this problem, because my IDE's autocomplete feature added a dependency to resolve the undeclared `cy` object – that gets injected by cypress.

```js
const { default: cy } = require('date-fns/esm/locale/cy/index.js');
```

This was very unfortunate, as there is an [ongoing (in 2022) issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-documentation/issues/2565) with the custom commands and you can find a tons of hints..

Answer (score 0):

Removing

```
import { cy } from "date-fns/locale";
```

or similar import

from the test file, resolved this. This gets added automatically to resolve undeclared cy objects

Permanent Solution: Add the following to cypress.json

```
"compilerOptions": {
   "types": ["cypress"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added at the top of `commands.js`.

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />
export{}

//CUSTOM COMMANDS...
```

This then exported and exposed the custom commands after `cy.` .