# Adding custom functions for Synpress/Cypress Project

Tags: javascript, cypress, e2e-testing, metamask, cypress-custom-commands

I want to add [custom functions](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands#Syntax) to a synpress [project](https://github.com/yvesbou/dappify-studio-e2e). (Synpress is a wrapper around Cypress which allows interaction with Metamask). Note there is a question: [Cypress custom command is not recognized when invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47695535/cypress-custom-command-is-not-recognized-when-invoked/47707642#47707642.) but even though I read through this QA, my custom functions are not recognized.

This is my project setup.

```
synpress_project/
├─ cypress/
│  ├─ e2e/
│  ├─ support/
├─ package-lock.json
├─ package.json
```

From the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47695535/cypress-custom-command-is-not-recognized-when-invoked/47707642#47707642.) mentioned before

> All the code and referenced modules in index.js are loaded before your
> test file. So you need to refer(require) commands.js in your index.js
> file

I obeyed to that, inside `cypress/support`:

##### commands.js

```
import "@testing-library/cypress/add-commands";

// add it here, because custom functions need synpress commands as well
import "@synthetixio/synpress/support";

// add custom functions

Cypress.Commands.add("disconnectFromDappify", () => {
    cy.disconnectMetamaskWalletFromDapp().should("be.true");
  });
```

##### index.js

```
import './commands'
```

I know that the files are being read, since removing the line `import "@synthetixio/synpress/support";` breaks the tests (metamask interaction does not work anymore). However, my function is not available

```
TypeError: cy.disconnectFromDappify is not a function
```

#### package.json

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^10.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "env-cmd -f .env npx synpress run -cf synpress.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@synthetixio/synpress": "^1.2.0",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0"
  }
}
```

#### synpress.json

```
{
    "baseUrl": "http://localhost:3000",
    "userAgent": "synpress",
    "retries": { "runMode": 0, "openMode": 0 },
    "integrationFolder": "cypress/e2e/specs",
    "screenshotsFolder": "screenshots",
    "videosFolder": "videos",
    "video": false,
    "chromeWebSecurity": true,
    "viewportWidth": 1366,
    "viewportHeight": 850,
    "component": {
      "componentFolder": ".",
      "testFiles": "**/*spec.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    },
    "env": {
      "coverage": false
    },
    "defaultCommandTimeout": 30000,
    "pageLoadTimeout": 30000,
    "requestTimeout": 30000,
    "supportFile": "cypress/support/index.js"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of a colleague, I was able to solve it.

Although, I specified `"supportFile": "cypress/support/index.js"` inside the `synpress.json`. It could not find the custom functions.

But if I changed the way the supportFile is called, *explicit instead of implicit*, it works.

Add `--supportFile='cypress/support/index.js'` to the end of the command.

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "env-cmd -f .env npx synpress run -cf synpress.json --supportFile='cypress/support/index.js'"
  },
```

Additionally, remove `import "@testing-library/cypress/add-commands";` from the `commands.js` file. (don't know why this is needed, but code breaks, if used, any hints are welcome!)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a type definition for your custom command.

I would only expect the TypeError is you're using Typescript, but your file extensions say otherwise.

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />

declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable<Subject> {
    disconnectFromDappify(): Chainable<any>
  }
}

Cypress.Commands.add("disconnectFromDappify", () => {
  cy.disconnectMetamaskWalletFromDapp().should("be.true");
});
```

Comment: This does not work for me, unfortanetly.